# Redirect with parameters and display to view

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes

I am beginner to laravel 5.1

This is my code

```
route.php
''''''''''
Route::get('/', function(){
    $tasks = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return view('tasks', Array(
        'tasks' => $tasks,
    ));
});
Route::delete('/task/{id}', function ($id) {
    $parameters=Array(
        'alert_ada'=>"ada",
        'alert_msg'=>"No $id telah dibuang",
    );

    return redirect('/')->with($parameters);
});
```

..

```
view.php
''''''''
<html>
    <head>
        <script> 
           alert('{{$alert_msg}}+{{$alert_ada}}');
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

The problem is the parameters doesnt show into the view.php

Comment: Do you get any error in your Blade template, Or somewhere else?  And maybe you will use return view() and not redirect.

Comment: yes i got errors "Undefined variable"

Comment: Yeah! That's nice but you need to specify where you get the error. Are you using any controller?

Comment: i just editted my code above

Comment: Ye I have seen that. I see you are using the routes to do your tasks. Are you using any Controller and  Model for this? Have you tryied to not redirect but to use ' return view()'  instead?

Comment: @Franco Thanks for trying to help.. but i just solved it...
i just post my solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved it!

```
Route::get('/', function(){
   $tasks = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

   $alert_ada = Session::get('alert_ada');
   $alert_msg = Session::get('alert_msg');

   return view('tasks', Array(
       'tasks' => $tasks,
       'alert_ada'=>$alert_ada,
       'alert_msg'=>$alert_msg,
   ));
});


Route::delete('/task/{id}', function ($id) {
   $parameters=Array(
       'alert_ada'=>"ada",
       'alert_msg'=>"No $id telah dibuang",
   );

   return redirect('/')->with($parameters);
});
```